# PHP: Recognize junction point on Windows (PHP5/Apache 2.4)

Tags: php, windows, hyperlink, junction

Is there any way to recognize if a folder is a junction point in PHP on a windows system? Or even get the path / name of the target?

`is_link` or `realpath` do not support it.

Thanks!

Comment: If you know the shell command you have at least a [workaround](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php).

Comment: Yes, thought of using some command, but don't know one yet.

Comment: maybe helpful: https://github.com/contao-community-alliance/composer-plugin/issues/34

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by using **lstat()**, see http://php.net/manual/de/function.lstat.php

It returns an array with pieces of information about the filename (dir/junction). You need compare the key `mode` against a certain bitmask.

`mode` equals `st_mode` in the underlying OS layer.
The `_stat` struct is defined in `SYS\STAT.H`. It includes a field `st_mode`.

About the `st_mode` bitmask:

> Bit mask for file-mode information. The _S_IFDIR bit is set if path
>   specifies a directory; the _S_IFREG bit is set if path specifies an
>   ordinary file or a device. User read/write bits are set according to
>   the file's permission mode; user execute bits are set according to the
>   filename extension.

```
     * #define  _S_IFDIR    0x4000
     * #define  _S_IFREG    0x8000
```

Quoted from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stat-functions?view=vs-2017

---

PHP Implementation for **isJunction()**: https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Util/Filesystem.php#L654-L678

**Warning** This is very fragile after the lastest changes to Windows. See https://www.bountysource.com/issues/53997655-composer-update-is-deleting-pathed-windows-symlinked-local-repos-again-ref-4955